# Is it possible to link a cmake project to subprojects?

Tags: c++, cmake, build-process

I have a C++ library project which comes with an `examples` folder. The examples are stand-alone, i.e. they can be compiled without the rest of the source tree as if they were real applications using the library. They use the provided `FindMyLib.cmake` to find the installed library in the system.

I would like to *also* be able to build them along with the whole library. Initially, I added them as subdirectories:

```
if(MYLIB_BUILD_EXAMPLES)
    add_subdirectory(examples/fooexample)
    add_subdirectory(examples/barexample)
endif()
```

But this is won't work, because I can't use `find_package` before the library is installed. I can add the default build directory to the search path, but that's not enough because the library is not built yet while cmake is running (obviously).

What can I do to solve this? Is there a way to transparently link the library to these subprojects while building it (and also "disable" the find_package, since it is bound to fail without an installation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just prepare *fake* `FindMyLib.cmake`, which links to the library using *build* tree, not an *install* one. E.g., it may set variable `MyLib_LIBRARY` variable to library *target*:

**cmake-build/FindMyLib.cmake**:

```
set(MyLib_LIBRARY MyLib)
set(MyLib_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
...
```

Then prepend `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` list with directory, contained fake script. Such a way it will be used by examples:

```
if(MYLIB_BUILD_EXAMPLES)
    set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-build ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
    add_subdirectory(examples/fooexample)
    add_subdirectory(examples/barexample)
endif()
```

Comment: Unless I missed something, this will not work: the configuration step for the examples will lead to an error, because the library will not be built yet,

Comment: If library is added (with `add_library(MyLib)`) *before* `add_subdirectory(examples/...)`, then `target_link_libraries(fooexample ${MyLib_LIBRARY})` works as usual linking with **target**. Library target is not required to be built at this stage.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for getting back this late. I really like this solution because it has the added benefit of being able to have a CMakeLists.txt for the examples that has not conditional logic for in-tree builds.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to check, in your examples, whether the target that builds `MyLib` exists, and use it as a dependency if it does; invoke `find_library()` otherwise.

```
add_library(MyLib ...)

# examples/fooexample
if(NOT TARGET MyLib)
  find_library(MyLib)
endif()

add_executable(foo)

if(TARGET MyLib)
  add_dependencies(foo MyLib)
endif()
```